# Redirect from void action

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a void function that based on a conditional statement should redirect users to a different action.

```
public void MyFunction()
{
  if (!condition)
  {
    Redirect(url);
  }
...
...
}
```

Using redirect without a return statement doesn't seem to work.  Is there a more suitable method for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect("Some URL")` or `Server.Transfer("Some URL")` can be used to redirect any web page

`Response.Redirect("Some URL")` should be used when to :

- redirect the request to some plain HTML pages on our
  server or to some other web server
- not to care about causing additional roundtrips to the server on each request
- not need to preserve Query String and Form Variables from the original request
- to be able to see the new redirected URL where he is
  redirected in his browser (and be able to bookmark it if its
  necessary)

`Server.Transfer("Some URL")` should be used when to:

- transfer current page request to another .aspx page on the
  same server
- preserve server resources and avoid the
  unnecessary roundtrips to the server
- preserve Query String and Form Variables (optionally) we don't need to show the real URL

  where we redirected the request in the users Web Browser

Comment: Response.Redirect wont work either.  The entire action is executed.  ie. Response.Redirect(url) and Redirect(url) don't stop execution of the action and redirect to anywhere.

Comment: It must be but please read the paper. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public IActionResult MyFunction()
{
  if (!condition)
  {
    return Redirect(url);
  }
   ...
   ...
}
```

About **IActionResult**

> Actions can return anything, but frequently return an instance of
>   IActionResult (or Task for async methods) that produces
>   a response. The action method is responsible for choosing what kind of
>   response. The action result does the responding.

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions
You may get more information about action methods at above link

Comment: The function doesn't have a return value so using IActionResult will throw a build error for "Not all paths have a return value"

Comment: you need to have an else part.Because you need to say or show something to the user.

Comment: you can consider adding return BadRequest() in the else part.  Bad request means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules to satisfy your condition

Comment: Actually I'm using this void method to respond to an AJAX call from a client-side script which just inserts a record into one of my tables.  It isn't used to display anything to the user, hence the reason I'm using a 'void' function.  However, the condition that I'm testing for is to determine the 'Active' value of the user who is attempting the insert and redirecting them to a page which tells them to activate their account.

Comment: IMHO If it is an ajax call you need to do the redirect at the client side.From the server return a response with a bad request or unauthorized status.Then from the client side do the redirection as needed.

Comment: @LuciFer You won't be able to redirect them from an AJAX call. The user will just get served the page you want to redirect them to through javascript (which they wont see). You should be serving status codes instead and redirecting client side.